# Necesito ayuda en mi código de MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

```
    Delimiter //
create procedure eval (IN matricula INT, nombre varchar(60),ap_paterno varchar(70),ap_materno varchar(60), sexo char(1), fecha_nac date, prome INT)

begin
declare variable1 char(30);
if prome >=98 && prome<=100 then
set variable1='AU';

if prome >=97 && prome<=97 then
set variable1='DE';

if prome >=80 && prome<=89 then
set variable1='SA';
else
set variable1='AS';
end if;
end if;
end if;
insert into uttec values (matricula, nombre, ap_paterno, ap_materno, sexo, fecha_nac,promedio,variable1);
end //
```

Al insertar los Siguientes Valores me arroja lo siguiente: `"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
call eval(252426,"Daniel","Horta","Delgado","H",'1994-06-26',60)//
```

Ayuda!

Comment: Seria de ayuda ver un describe de tu tabla uttec no ?

Comment: Puede ser que la tabla uttec tenga alguna columna demás o menos, que lo que indicas en el INSERT INTO

Comment: Siguiendo lo que te dicen los demás, es recomendable, cuando haces `insert`, explicitar el nombre de las columnas, para ver in situ que la cantidad de campos iguala a la de valores, así te evitas posibles errores como estos.

Comment: ejecuta el comando describe uttec y muestranos el resultado para ver si los campos coinciden